# Is there an $a_{k} \in (0, 1)$ such that $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}(1 - a_k)\prod_{j = 1}^{k - 1}a_j$ diverges?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a_k \in (0, 1)$. Are there any $a_k$ one can choose such that $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}(1 - a_k)\prod_{j = 1}^{k - 1}a_j$ diverges? All of the choices I've tried ($a_k = 1/k, 1/2, 1/2^k$, etc.) seem to converge.

Comment: Do you know what the partial sums of this series look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p_k=\prod_{j=1}^ka_j$. Then you ask about $\sum_{k=1}^\infty(p_{k-1}-p_k)$. This is a telescope series and converges to $a_0-\lim_{k\to\infty} p_k$. Note that $\lim_{k\to\infty} p_k$ will exist as it is a strictly decreasing bounded sequence.